# How to remove the event listeners of all buttons when only one is clicked

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I'm doing a quiz app, and when the user picks an answer, I want to display the next question. The thing is, the event listener on the other buttons are not removed, only the button the user clicked (using once:true). Is there a way that I can remove all event listeners on the other buttons when only one of them is fired?

Here is my code:

```
   function enableButtons(correctAnswer) {
    
    btns.forEach((btn) => {
        btn.addEventListener(
            'click',
            function () {
                if (checkAnswer(btn.textContent, correctAnswer)) {
                    btn.classList.add('correctAnswer');
                } else {
                    btn.classList.add('wrongAnswer');
                }

                setTimeout(function () {
                    removeBtnClasses(btn),
                    nextQuestion()
                }, 2000);
            },
            {once: true}
        )
    })

}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

Comment: @CBroe That won't work here since the listeners are anonymous.

Comment: Don't add and remove the event listeners for each. Just make the correct answer a global variable that you update each time you display a new question.

Comment: @Barmar yes, I am aware, that part will have to get changed accordingly of course.

Comment: I read that. But it was not working, as the function in the event listener needed a parameter outside the event object, so I couldn't just create a function that I would pass to the event handler. That's the problem. What I did was create a global variable to hold the value I needed, so now I can pass the function in the event listener, but I feel like it is such an ugly way of doing it.

Comment: @barmar I did exactly that. I created a 'correctAnswer' variable, so now I can access it anywhere I want. But isn't this bad code or an ugly way of doing it?

Comment: As a general rule we try to avoid global variables. But sometimes they're the most obvious and practical solution. In thie case, if there's just one question at a time, a global variable is fine. If you have to support multiple questions, you could use an object or map, you could put the information in related DOM elements, etc.

Comment: @enricocaliolo you can have one event listener for all of the buttons using [event delegation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#event_delegation).

Answer (score 0):

You can write removeEventListener method.

A guide for removeEventListener :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener

And I am not sure about second method but I think you can add disabled attribute to the button, I haven't worked with DOM for long time so I don't remember if second method would work.